# How to look for multiple strings in a text and count the number of strings found?

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching

I have a list of strings and a text file. The list is composed of strings containing 1 token and other strings containing more than 1 because they are proper nouns. It looks like: ['ana e joao','fab g. ruggeri', 'resende', 'Ana e Joao'].

with my code, I find the strings in the text file but I do not know how to count the frequency of occurrence of each string found.

I've tried to store the strings in a file separated by ',' read the file and split by ','. I also read the file and I try to match all the strings in the text file at once but I need to count how many time each string occurs in the text file. See code below:

```
def proper_nouns():
    with open('/Users/proper_nouns.txt','r', encoding="utf-8") as 
p:
        pn = p.read()
        s=pn.split(',')


    while True:
        try:
            f =Path(input("\Enter your file path : "))
            with open(f,'r', encoding="utf-8") as fi:
                wds = fi.read()
                break
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("\nTry again")

    propn_found=[y for y in s if x in wds]



    print(propn_found)

def proper_nouns()
```

I want to find all these strings in a text file at once, count the frequency of occurrence of each string in the text file and print them like:

"Ana" 2
"Ana e Joao" 3
"Resende" 4

and so on...

Comment: check [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply dict comprehension to generate dictionary with required data:

```
text = "some random text apple, some text ginger, some other blob data"
words = "some", "text", "blob"
result = {word: text.count(word) for word in words}
```

Output:

```
{'some': 3, 'text': 2, 'blob': 1}
```

---

**Upd.**

To solve problem with recognizing words I recommend to use regular expression:

```
import re
...
result = {word: re.subn(r"\b{}\b".format(word), "", text)[1] for word in words}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That works, but there is a problem: when there is a proper noun that is a single string such as 'So' if the text contains any word with this string in its structure such as 'Solid', the program will add this part of the word as one more occurrence of it. Do you have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it manually without any libraries and iterating over the text this should work:

```
def proper_nouns():

    wordsfilepath = '/Users/proper_nouns.txt'
    textfilepath = '/Users/text.txt'
    with open(wordsfilepath,'r', encoding="utf-8") as p:
        words = p.read()
        words = words.split(',')
    with open(textfilepath, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as textfile:
        searchtext = textfile.read()
        searchtext = searchtext.strip()
    wordDict = {}
    for word in searchtext:
        try:
              wordDict[word] = wordDict[word]+1
        except IndexError:
              wordDict[word] = 1
    for word in wordDict:
        print(f"{word}, wordDict[word]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Where is the file containing the strings to be matched being read in this code? I only see the code reading the text, but not the file with the strings.

Comment: Oh whoops sorry I will add that.